# Fourier Transform Goes to Zero

Tags: real-analysis

Exercise

Let $f \in L^1(R)$.  Its Fourier transform is defined by

$$F(t) = \int f(x)e^{-2\pi i x t}dx$$

Show that the $lim_{|t| \rightarrow \infty} |F(x)| = 0 $

Solution:

$ lim_{|t| \rightarrow \infty} |F(x)| = lim_{|t| \rightarrow \infty } |\int f(x)e^{-2\pi i x t}|dx \le \int |f(x)||e^{-2\pi i x t}|dx \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} M*e^{-2\pi i x t} = 0 $

Where $M$ is such that $||f|| \le M$ since $f\in L^1(E)$ and is therefore bounded.  I also make use of Holder's Inequality.

Does this proof look okay?

Comment: No, this is not anywhere near sharp enough. The problem is that $|e^{-2\pi i x t}| = 1$ for all $x, t$, so that your final inequality isn't correct - the bound you've shown is that $|F(x)| \le \|f\|_1$ for almost every $x$.

Answer (score 2):

No, this proof is not correct. The problem is that there is no decay of the *complex* exponential $e^{-2\pi i x t}$ as $t \to \pm \infty$, so that doesn't give any bound - in fact, $|e^{-2\pi i x t}| = 1$ for all real $x$ and $t$, so you've only established that

$$|F(x)| \le \|f\|_{L^1}$$

(which is still useful).

---

For a different approach, perhaps consider the following outline:

- Show that the claim is true for compactly supported continuous functions. Here, uniform continuity can be used to your advantage, together with the oscillatory nature of the complex exponential.
- Now use the density of such functions in $L^1$. In fact, from what you've shown above, we have that the pointwise difference between $G$ and $F$ can be controlled using control on the $L^1$-norm difference between $g$ and $f$.

[Alternatively](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_Lemma), do this for characteristic functions, hence simple functions, hence $L^1$ functions via a density argument.

---

For reference, this is called the [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).

Comment: Great answer, and though linked, writing down the name "Riemann Lebesgue Lemma" seems important to me! =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks, and you're right - I'll add a mention to this in the answer.